# How do I count files in 2 different directories and do a compare using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compare the number of files on a local folder to that of the source folder which is in a server.

I have the following lines in a batch file below but i always get the same value for both no matter what.

```
@for /f %%a in ('2^>nul dir "%local_folder%" /a/b/-o/-p/s^|find /v /c ""') do set n=%%a

echo Total files in Local Folder: %n%
pause

@for /f %%a in ('2^>nul dir "%source_folder%" /a/b/-o/-p/s^|find /v /c ""') do set m=%%a

echo Total files in Source Folder: %m%
pause

if %n%==%m% (copy update_folder local_folder.\ && goto end) else (goto copy_all_files)
pause
```

I am getting the same value for when I try to count the files in the separate locations. I only want to count the visible files with extension `*.wav` on each folder.

UPDATE: RESOLUTION I found is below,

```
:file_count_chck
set folder_cf=".\folder-A\*.wav"
set folder_lib="\\folder-B\*.wav"

dir %folder_cf% > A.txt
dir %folder_lib% > B.txt
set count_cf=0
for /f %%x in (A.txt) do set /a count_cf+=1
set count_lib=0
for /f %%y in (B.txt) do set /a count_lib+=1
set data_lines=5
set /A count_cf = %count_cf%-%data_lines% 
set /A count_lib = %count_lib%-%data_lines% 
echo.
echo Checking Sound folder...
echo Sound files on CF card = %count_cf%
echo Sound files on library = %count_lib%
del "A.txt" "B.txt"
set /a difference_count=%count_lib%-%count_cf%

if %difference_count% EQU 0 (echo Ok && goto wav_update) else (echo Detected missing files and correcting && goto copy_all_wav)
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: `dir "%local_folder%\*.wav" /A:-D /B /S` to filter for `*.wav` files. Anyway, what if you delete a certain file from one location and another one from the other location, so the counts are still the same? Perhaps [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) could help you, particularly the `/D` option; or you go for [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which has got even more sync features...

Comment: When you say visible files in the location, are you supposed to be including all of their subdirectories? Either way, you really need to read the help for the commands you're using and try them before asking questions for which the answers are readily available, e.g. `for /?`, `dir /?`, `find /?` etc. For example to return all  non hidden, _(visible)_, `.wav` files in a directory, `Dir /B /A:-D-H "D:\irectory\*.wav"`, or the same but including also any subdirectories, `Dir /B /S /A:-D-H "D:\irectory\*.wav"`.

Comment: Thank you aschipfl and Compo for your comments. I need help as I can't seem to figure out how to do the counting and assign it to separate variables and do a compare for do an action afterward.

Comment: Resolved my own question.